# macOS update gone wrong: "Startup disk could not gather enough information on the selected disk"

Tags: macos, installation, updates

During an OS update through the App Store last night my system failed to update. It tells me to quit the installer, which I've tried multiple times but the only system option it gives me to restart has an error message that reads:

> "Startup disk could not gather enough information on the selected disk"?

Nothing seems to be working. Has anyone experienced this before?

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

1. You should start with reseting PRAM, turn off laptop, turn it on holding <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> - laptop should boot, then reboot and load as usual.
2. If "1" did not helped: check if you can access Recovery partition, power on laptop and click and hold <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, if you see options like: "Restore from Time Machine Backup" , "Reinstall OS X" or Get Help Online... go to "Disk Utility".  Open Disk Utility and run "Frist aid". That should perform fileshare check.
3. If "2" did not help, and you have Time Machine backup, user recovery again, and recover from last backup (if it suits you).
4. If "3" is not an option, you can try to boot in single user mode and try to repair it yourself: during boot-up hold <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, you will see just terminal information what has been loaded, log in to system as root, enter commands:

   ```
   fsck -fy
   ```

   when filesystem check is done, you can exit and reboot:

   ```
   exit
   ```
5. If that did not help, and you have at least your user home folder backup, you can use Internet Recovery: <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> it will first download macOS X Recovery partition, and then the OS with which your Mac was sold. Then update OS, and copy folder of your username to Users folder, then create in users and groups exact same login as folder you've moved and when asked confirm to connect content of that folder with this new user.

That is all I can figure out for now.